# What does this syntax mean relating to interface declaration?

Tags: objective-c, interface

This is from the ViewController.m file in a starter project from a tutorial for a game.

```
@interface ViewController()

//irrelevant stuff omitted

@end
```

It's the `ViewController()` bit that confuses me. I understand the different between public and private interfaces, but I haven't used a private interface til now in Objective-C. I'm used to seeing something like this instead, for the public interface:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
```

So why now is it just the first one, and with parentheses, with no inheritance notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a [class extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3). It allows for declaring additional interface, usually private because it's in an implementation (.m) file. It's similar to a category, except that the compiler will require you to supply the implementation for any interface declared within it. (A category can declare an interface even if nothing provides any implementation.)